# message: 'Unexpected token: punc (.)', while using uglify in grunt

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

## Goal

My goal is to **concatenate** all my css,js files and **minify** all of them.
I can minify my `concat.js`, but I'm struggling trying to minify my `concat.css`.

---

## Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    "use strict";

    grunt.initConfig({

        concat: {

            js: {
                src: [

                    'js/bootstrap.min.js',
                    'js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js',

                    'js/jquery.easypiechart.min.js',
                    'js/jquery.isotope.min.js',
                    'js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js',
                    'js/waypoints.min.js',
                    'js/respond.min.js',
                    'js/jquery.vegas.min.js',
                    'js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js',
                    'js/jquery.nav.js',
                    'js/html5shiv.js',
                    'js/jquery.scrollTo.js',
                    'js/jquery.sticky.js',
                    'js/jquery.validate.js',
                    'js/main.js',

                ],
                dest: 'dist/concat.js'
            },

            css: {
                src: [


                    'css/magnific-popup.css',
                    'css/main.css',
                    'css/xl.css',
                    'css/lg.css',
                    'css/md.css',
                    'css/sm.css',
                    'css/xs.css',
                    'css/print.css',
                    'css/bootstrap.min.css',
                    'css/font-awesome.min.css',

                ],
                dest: 'dist/concat.css'
            }
        },

        watch: {

            js: {

                files: ['js/*.js'],
                task: ['concat:js']
            },

            css: {
                files: ['css/*.css'],
                task: ['concat:css']
            }
        },

        uglify: {

            js: {
                files: {
                    'dist/minified.js': ['dist/concat.js']
                }
            },

            css: {
                files: {
                    'dist/minified.css': ['dist/concat.css']
                }
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'uglify']);

};
```

---

## Result

I concatenate all my css and js files succesfully, and they're generated at :

- `dist/concat.js`
- `dist/concat.css`

Then, I can also minify my `concat.js` with no problem, but I'm struggling trying to minify my `concat.css`.

I kept getting this **error** in the bottom of my Terminal :

```
Running "uglify:css" (uglify) task
{ message: 'Unexpected token: punc (.)',
  filename: 'concat.css',
  line: 4,
```

and line4 is just the beginning of my class : `.mfp-bg {`

Can someone please give me a little push here ?
Also, should I perform minify after concatenation or the other way around ?
Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: That's because `uglify` is for minimising JavaScript only, and not CSS.

Comment: Dang it. Thanks for stopping me trying to debug sth that is impossible. Do you have any suggestions for me to accomplish this ?

Comment: I guess I'll just use this : https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`uglify` is for minimising JavaScript only, not CSS.

If you want to minimise CSS you can use the [cssmin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-cssmin) task for Grunt instead.